# Dawn of the Jedi: Into the Void

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In the novel, *Star Wars Dawn of the Jedi: Into the Void*, where is the closure?

> Lanoree kills her brother and then goes back to the temple. When she gets there, her master says that a ship carrying force sensitives from out of system had crashed on Tython. In the next chapter, Lanoree and Hawk Ryo are facilitating negotiations on the moon of Zerist. Then they finish and go home and the book ends.

What about the force sensitives from out of system and what about the hyper gate?  They say that big changes are coming and then they just never touch the issue again and end the book. I was really hoping to see the Je'daii break away from the Tython system and meet the rest of the galaxy.

Comment: I've not read it, but surely it ties into the comic serial? http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dawn_of_the_Jedi:_Into_the_Void

Comment: The evidence seems to suggest that there is none...?

Comment: Going off Richard's comment... the concept of "closure" is primarily opinion based. Also, the answer might be, "It was left open on purpose" as many works in a series are.